# Alias for open last directory in the current directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I want create alias for open the last directory in the current directory, maybe I think it's possible to use  this command for get name of directory : 
 ls -1t | head -1
But I don't say to use it.

solved with function or with alias :
alias oo='cd $(ls -1t | head -1)'

Comment: You almost have it: `cd $(ls -1t | tail -1)` makes it.

Comment: What do you mean by _last directory_? do you mean the last modified directory or the last with respect to sorting by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't create an alias! from `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

So unless you really know what the alias mechanism is, and you know you really need an alias, use a function instead.

The following function will get you to the last directory (with respect to sorting by name) of the current directory:

```
cdlast() {
    local shoptnullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)
    shopt -s nullglob
    local dirs=( */ )
    $shoptnullglob
    ((${#dirs[@]})) && cd -- "${dirs[-1]}"
}
```

A few remarks: this will not take the hidden directories into account, unless have set the shell option `dotglob`. If there are not directories in the current directory, the function does nothing (but has a return code of 1).

---

If you need to cd into the last modified directory, things get trickier (and hence more interesting):

```
cdlast() {
    local shoptnullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)
    shopt -s nullglob
    local dirs=( */ )
    $shoptnullglob
    ((${#dirs[@]})) || return 1
    local last=${dirs[0]}
    for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        [[ $d -nt $last ]] && last=$d
    done
    cd -- "$last"
}
```

If you like these functions, put them in you `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

The command you mentioned cannot differentiate between files and dirs, use the following instead:

```
LAST_DIR=$(ls -ltr | egrep ^d | awk '{ print $9 }'| head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dirs=(*/)             # an array of directories in the CWD
last_dir=${dirs[-1]}  # the "last" directory lexicographically
```